# Biometric not detected in Samsung galaxy M01 device with Android Q?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Following is my code to detect biometric functionality

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var executor: Executor? = null
    private var biometricPrompt: BiometricPrompt? = null
    private var promptInfo: BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bioMetricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)

        when (bioMetricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> {
                executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)

                promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder().setTitle("Biometric login for leaao")
                    .setSubtitle("Log in using biometric credentials").setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true).build()

                biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this,
                    executor!!, object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                        override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                            Log.i("here4","Authentication error: $errString")
                        }

                        override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                            Log.i("here5","Success")
                        }

                        override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                            super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                            Log.i("here6","Authentication failed: ")
                        }
                    })

                biometricPrompt?.authenticate(promptInfo!!)
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> {
                Log.i("here","No biometric features available on this device.")
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                Log.i("here2","Biometric features are currently unavailable.")
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> {
                Log.i("here3","The user hasn't associated any biometric credentials with their account.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />` to Manifest file and added `implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1'` to gradle

Still my code fails to detect biometric prompt. I have enabled face recognition on my mobile but it does not work when i open my app. It goes to `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE` case in my code.

Comment: what is the behavior when you add fingerprints as preference in device settings ?

Comment: @Shanker I dont have fingerprint option in my device.

Comment: Looks like face authentication in device is not compatible with Android Biometric stack.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `BiometricManager` seeks `BIOMETRIC_STRONG` sensors on the device, unless you specify them in `.setAllowedAutnenticators()`. However, you should know that as of now, there are no devices with STRONG face/iris sensors. That means that only the fingerprint sensor is "seen" as STRONG and all of the face and iris sensors (with some exceptions, where they are not seen as a sensor at all) are "seen" as `BIOMETRIC_WEAK`. With "seen" I mean they were set as such by the manufacturer. So having said that, something like this should be able to fix your issue:

```
BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
.setTitle(...)
.setDescription(...)
.setAllowedAuthenticators(
    BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG or
                        BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK
)
```

and when checking for available authentication:

```
when (BiometricManager.from(requireContext()).canAuthenticate(
                BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG
                        or BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK
            )) { ... }
```